# My shuffle function works in singular but when combining multiple calls into one function it breaks

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I must be missing some basic principle here but the function shuffle works as intended however when I try and call multiple times inside another function any call after the first results in an array filled with 52 undefined entries.

```
function shuffle(array) {
    let newDeck = [];

    for (i=52; i>0; i--) {
        let randomPick = Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length));

        newDeck.push(array[randomPick]);
        deck.splice(randomPick, 1);
    }
    deck = newDeck;
    console.log(deck);
}

function fullShuffle(cards) {
    shuffle(cards);
    shuffle(cards);
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `deck`?

Comment: or, return deck...
or, pass in the deck to be shuffled...
your function creates a deck...

Comment: Sorry new to this and forgot that important bit of code.

Comment: let deck = [
    "ac", "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "10c", "jc", "qc", "kc",
    "ad", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "10d", "jd", "qd", "kd",
    "ah", "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "10h", "jh", "qh", "kh",
    "as", "2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "10s", "js", "qs", "ks",
];

Comment: if i simply run

Comment: shuffle(deck); multiple times everything works fine

Comment: You remove cards from deck and read from array? Sounds fishy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array Use that to shuffle your array,

Comment: So you have `deck`, `cards` , `newDeck`, `array` ... that are quite a lot of deck of cards. Why so many? And why pass an argument when you actually seem to have a global variable? Or better, why a global variable when you have a function argument, and could return the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not complete in the question, but it seems `deck` is a global variable, which you also pass as argument to `fullShuffle`. The issue is that  `deck.splice` empties that array completely in one call of `shuffle`, so that if you use that `deck` again and it gets passed via `fullShuffle` to `shuffle` again, you are passing an empty array and `array[randomPick]` will be undefined for all 52 iterations (as `array` is the same reference as `deck` if my assumption about the rest of your is right).

If you want to implement your shuffle this way, then:

- Don't use a global variable inside that function
- Rely only on the argument that the function gets
- Take a copy of that array, so that you can happily splice without affecting the array of the caller
- Return the shuffled array to the caller

Code:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    let newDeck = [];
    array = [...array]; // take copy!

    for (i=52; i>0; i--) {
        let randomPick = Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length));

        newDeck.push(array[randomPick]);
        array.splice(randomPick, 1);
    }
    console.log(newDeck);
    return newDeck; // return it.
}

function fullShuffle(cards) {
    cards = shuffle(cards); // capture the returned, shuffled array
    cards = shuffle(cards);
    return cards; // return to caller
}

// can be called like this:

var deck = [ "ac", "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "10c", "jc", "qc", "kc", "ad", "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "10d", "jd", "qd", "kd", "ah", "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "10h", "jh", "qh", "kh", "as", "2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "10s", "js", "qs", "ks" ];
deck = fullShuffle(deck);
```

Although for a human shuffle it makes sense to shuffle the same deck twice, for a function like this, there is little sense in calling it twice. It is like you don't trust the function to shuffle randomly enough...

Note also that there are better implementations of `shuffle`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) where you find implementations of the Durstenfeld algorithm.

Comment: Thanks so much, Im very new to this and wanted to create something simple with no framework. i realise the need to shuffle more than once in a function like this compared to a human shuffle makes no sense but i thought it would be fun to replicate that action in code. And in doing so i created a problem for myself and have remebered/learnt about returning resultsand assigning them to variables!